# Clean upgrade instructions for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-wiki

I am trying to follow the instructions for doing a clean upgrade at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CleanUpgrade. The first part of the instructions is to remove everything in Synaptic's status section "Installed ( local or obsolete )". In Ubuntu 18.04 the package "network-manager" and it s supporting packages are in that section for me. I can hardly believe I should remove all the package which support my network connection to the Internet before I try upgrading, else the upgrade files can never be downloaded to my machine. is there a solution for this recommendation or should I just ignore it entirely ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Can you please clarify which section you refer to, as I read it only referring to third-party packages (ie. not Ubuntu or Canonical official packages) which is not how I read your question.  (*please don't take this as questioning your understanding, I'm interested to see if there are problems with the wiki that I can easily correct*)

Comment: Also what are you trying to upgrade to?   Ubuntu 18.04 LTS being a long-term-support release is usually upgraded to the next LTS (ie. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) which isn't offered until 20.04.1's release next year.  Yes you can opt out of the LTS path (ie. to 18.10 which is EOL next month, then 19.04, 19.10 then 20.04) but is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: The best upgrade instructions from 18.04 to 18.10 are the release notes (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes)  in the *Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04* section.  This would be the first place I'd look as they are specific to upgrade paths, rather than the generic detail you looked at.  If you are attempting to upgrade to 18.04 (and not from 18.04) then https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes (which has a *Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 17.10* section)

Comment: I am trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04, but the only way to currently do that is to go first from 18.04 to 18.10 and then from 18.10 to 19.04. In Synaptic there is a status section called "Installed ( local or obsolete )", to which the clean upgrade instructions refer. Thanks for the link to the release notes. I will look at that. My previous attempts to upgrade to 18.10 always led to failure ( more about that in another future post ), so I have been trying to follow the advice at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CleanUpgrade.

Comment: The only supported way is from 18.04 to 18.10; the only skips allowed by Ubuntu are from one LTS to the next LTS (ie. the 18.04 to 20.04 when released).  Your alternative (ignoring many unofficial sites that give you untested & unofficial methods that may/may-not work) is to use install media for 19.04, use 'something-else' and replace your existing partitions **without format**.  This will cause the installer to note your added packages, erase system directories, install, re-add back your additional packages (if from Ubuntu repos) without touching your user files.  Note: you must not format

Comment: ..  It's easy to miss the format check-box, so of course backup first. I realize that was the link, but I'm lost as to where you got 'network-manager' in a section that should be removed.  I can only imagine this being a misunderstanding, or you've added unofficial sources and replaced official packages with unofficial ones that have put that key component into non-Ubuntu places.  Tools upgrade to the latest version of packages, so unofficial sources often intentionally put higher-versions on packages so they replace official to easy install, but causing problems on release-upgrade like now

Comment: Given that I can try to use a 19.04 installation disk, what is the 'something-else' which you mention above ? Is this an installation choice ? BTW I always take recent backups of my Ubuntu partitions before I try to upgrade from one release to another.

Comment: You write your Ubuntu 19.04 (or any flavor/release of Ubuntu) install media to dvd; boot it and you'll end up with try-ubuntu or install.  The install options will be listed and a 'something-else' option at the bottom which is what I was referring to. It allows you to manually choose your partitions and select if you want to format them or not (ie. it's a manual/advanced option).  Before installing I write down on a scrap of paper my existing partition scheme (eg. 27gb sda /, 9gb sda2 swap,  24gb sda4 /home, 26gb /other, etc) so I know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I wrote that page about a decade before this question and it hadn't been updated in four years at the time of the asking, so keep that in mind. It's the community help wiki, not official documentation. Synaptic isn't used as the default package GUI any more. The "local and obsolete" section is packages without a source anymore; if network-manager is in there, that indicated something wrong. I imagine the original poster has moved on well before now but commenting in case somebody finds this in a search....